# Pattern for a db patch script

Tags: sql-server, database, oracle

I'm looking for a pattern to follow for a database patch script. We've had problems with customers not running patches, or running them in the wrong order, patches failing etc. and we'd like to get on top of it. We're using SqlServer and Oracle, but I'd like tips for making the scripts db agnostic if possible.

I think what I'm after is an idiot-proof script that we can re-run without creating duplicate entries and that will leave no trace if it fails mid-way through. e.g. something like this:

```
INSERT INTO auditTable (scriptName, txt, dt) VALUES "$nameOfScript$" "starting", $date.now$
begin transaction
check auditTable to see if script has not already been run successfully?
upserts? (insert into ... where not exist)
INSERT INTO auditTable (scriptName, txt, dt) VALUES "$nameOfScript$", "completed ok", $date.now$
commit transaction
```

This seems to me like it may be well known ground and that I ought to be copying some template, is there one?

(This is a cross post from: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/292101/boiler-plate-pattern-for-a-db-patch-script)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could capture the following details. Most of these are gathered from Oracle Applications (ERP)

- PATCH_NUMBER / SCRIPT NAME
- PATCH_DESCRIPTION
- PATCH_ACTION_OPTIONS - input parameters for script
- START_DATE
- END_DATE
- SUCCESS_FLAG
- FAILURE_COMMENTS
- EXECUTED_BY
- LAST_STEP -  include the last committed step here. the scripts can use this during restart. i.e. start this step onwards